# binding data to longlistselector listheadertemplate using wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, longlistselector

I want bind list of images to list box which is placed in longlistselector header template. 
So how to bind longlistselector header template dynamically.

Comment: From where you get the images? from web or added in your project.

Comment: Check this and try to expand your questions with the code you have tried. I will help you http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios

Comment: Can you please provide the cod you are currently using?

Answer (score 3):

The same way you'll do it on WP8...
Take a look at my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246368/bind-item-related-variable-to-listheader-in-longlistselector-wp8/16569046#16569046)
I hope it helped...