# Bind item-related variable to listheader in longlistselector (WP8)

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-7, xaml, header

I'm new to Windows Phone development and I'm currently facing an issue while using the LongListSelector in WP8, and I don't know how to proceed to achieve the result I want.

I use it to display a list of items as usual. The class used contains 5 items, and one of them is a float value. I want to display, in the list header, the sum of all positive float values contained in the list, but I have no idea whatsoever about how to do this.

I tried to bind another variable (result of the sum) specificly to the listheader in addition to the original binding, or to add another item in the class containing the sum result (hence repeated throughout the list in each list item), but it didn't work.

I guess this is a pretty basic fonctionnality (for instance to count and display the number of elements of the list), but I can't figure out how to do this.

EDIT : I thought showing my code wouldn't help, but here it is. (I took away the formatting that wasn't relevant)

XAML

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ListeSolde" LayoutMode="List">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SommeTotale}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nom}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DerniereConnexion}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Depuis}" />                                        
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Solde}"  />
       </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
 </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Class definition

```
public class resume
{
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public double Solde { get; set; }
    public string Depuis { get; set; }
    public string DerniereConnexion { get; set; }

    public resume(string nom, double solde, string depuis, string derniereconnexion)
    {
        this.Nom = nom;
        this.Solde = solde;
        this.Depuis = depuis;
        this.DerniereConnexion = derniereconnexion;
    }
}
public class total
{
    public double Total { get; set; }

    public double calculTotal(List<resume> soldes)
    {
        double total = new double();
        foreach (resume solde in soldes)
        {
            if (solde.Solde > 0)
                total += solde.Solde;
        }

        return total;
    }

    public total(double Dtotal)
    {
        this.Total = Dtotal;
    }
}
```

And code behind

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<resume> soldes = new List<resume>();

        Donnees MainData = new Donnees();
        soldes = MainData.RefreshResume(soldes); // A method that basically add items to the list

        total SommeTotale = new total(1);
        SommeTotale.Total = SommeTotale.calculTotal(soldes);

        ListeSolde.ItemsSource = soldes;
    }
```

This of course doesn't work (as far as the list header is concerned) and this is how I would do it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please show us your code?

Comment: Done. But I thought it wouldn't be helpful since my issue seems pretty generic.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I managed to bind other data from my ViewModel to the header of the LongListSelector.ListHeader.

```
<phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Foreground="DarkViolet"
                       Text="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.AddressBookList.Count}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ListHeader property binds directly to the DataContext of the LongListSelector. This is different that the items contained within the LongListSelector. The items contained within it are bound to each item within the ItemSource. One of the best ways to get the ListHeader to display is to create an object that houses the data for the LongListSelector

```
public class ResumeContainer
{
    public double SommeTotale { get { return Resumes.Sum(r => r.Value); } }
    public IEnumerable<Resume> Resumes { get; set; }
}
```

You would set the DataContext of the LongListSelector to be an instance of the ResumeContainer. This would preferably be a property of your ViewModel. You would need to change your xaml to be

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ListeSolde" ItemsSource="{Binding Resumes}">
```

Your code-behind then changes to

```
List<resume> soldes = new List<resume>();

Donnees MainData = new Donnees();
soldes = MainData.RefreshResume(soldes);
ListeSolde.DataContext = new ResumeContainer { Resumes = soldes };
```